# Access useState previous state object's key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Searched over stack overflow but found none similar (just replace an object key- value without using old value).

Consider a graph declared with useState

```
  const [graphBounds, setGraphBounds] = useState(graphBoundsInitialValue);
```

Where

```
const graphBoundsInitialValue = {
    left: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
};
```

Left and right are for X axis and bottom and top are for Y axis respectively.

I may have 1 or more graphs and for all of them I need to get minimum X, minimum Y, maximum X, maximum Y to display them correctly

I need to change one of the param of the `graphBounds` according to newcoming value from the server stored in `graph` variable and based on the old value of that param

I tried many things like

```
  setGraphBounds(prev => ({...prev, top : prev.top  > graph.maxY ? prev.top : graph.maxY}));
```

The issue is intellijIdea complains on that code and won't let me.
I tried [] brackets and so on but with no luck.

I've ended something like this:

```
const updatedTop = graphBounds.top > graph.maxY ? graphBounds.top : graph.maxY;

let updatedBottom = graphBounds.bottom < graph.minY ? graphBounds.bottom : graph.minY || 0; // bottom domain always above zero
updatedBottom = updatedBottom > 0 ? updatedBottom : 0;

const updatedLeft = graphBounds.left < graph.minX ? graphBounds.left : graph.minX;
const updatedRight = graphBounds.right > graph.maxX ? graphBounds.right : graph.maxX;

setGraphBounds({top: updatedTop, bottom: updatedBottom, left: updatedLeft, right: updatedRight});
```

This code always runs when new data comes and compare new graph value with the old one.

Still got an annoying feeling of non-optimized code.

P.S.

BUT if I even dare to make it, it will be still non-optimized 4 calls (yeah, in a batch but whatever) like

for left:     `setGraphBounds(prev => ({...prev, left : prev.left  > graph.minX ...`

for right:   `setGraphBounds(prev ...`

for top:   `setGraphBounds(prev...`

for bottom:   `setGraphBounds(prev...`

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: See `useReducer` instead of `useState`.

Comment: already did, to overcomplicated in my case: no need for actions

Comment: The "action" parameter can be anything though; e.g. the new `graph`, and your reducer can do all validation internally.

Answer (score 0):

You may face some problems because you are not accessing the current state `graphBounds`, example here:

```
const updatedTop =
    graphBounds.top > graph.maxY ? graphBounds.top : graph.maxY;
```

The value of `graphBounds` is not always the current value.

By using callback instead of object you will have access to latest version of your state `graphBounds`:

```
setGraphBounds((graphBounds) => {
  const updatedTop =
    graphBounds.top > graph.maxY ? graphBounds.top : graph.maxY;

  const updatedBottom =
    graphBounds.bottom < graph.minY ? graphBounds.bottom : graph.minY || 0; // bottom domain always above zero
  updatedBottom = updatedBottom > 0 ? updatedBottom : 0;

  const updatedLeft =
    graphBounds.left < graph.minX ? graphBounds.left : graph.minX;

  const updatedRight =
    graphBounds.right > graph.maxX ? graphBounds.right : graph.maxX;

  return {
    top: updatedTop,
    bottom: updatedBottom,
    left: updatedLeft,
    right: updatedRight,
  };
});
```

Comment: Ok, I know that set state is async but I use those values before any set state calls, why I am not accessing the actual current state in that case? Just defined all variables with current state and only then make 1 call to set state

Comment: Even you didn't call setState you may get the wrong state, the rule says that if want to update the next state from the current state, you shouldn't rely on state value.

Comment: if you want to update the state from the current state in the setState statement itself, but here the value was already evaluated